# Importing the data using command line data loader for multiple objects is possible by adding multiple beans (process.xml)?

Tags: batch, data-loader, commandline

Importing the data using command line data loader for multiple objects is possible by adding multiple beans in process.xml ?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to load multiple objects using the same process.xml file? Because yes, by adding a bean for each object load you can load multiple objects using one process.xml file.

Comment: @DanKowalski thank you so much :) and what about the files (mapping file) should it be separate ?

Comment: That depends. If you are doing three different loads on the same object that use the same field mapping you can use the same mapping file. However, if you are loading different objects then you will need a separate mapping file for each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have have multiple beans in one process.xml file. The below code example shows a process.xml file with mulitple beans.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="csvInsertSellerAccount"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          singleton="false">
        <description>Inserts Seller Account names from CSV file into Account object.</description>
        <property name="name" value="csvInsertSellerAccount"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\csvInsertSellerAccount.log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="username@username.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="EncryptedPassword"/>
                     <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\key.txt"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="540"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
                     <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Entity_Code__c"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="upsert"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\SellerAccountMapping.sdl"/>
                <entry key="process.outputError" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\errorInsertSellerAccount.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\successInsertSellerAccount.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\SellerAccount_1_100.csv" /> 
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" /> 
                <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2007-06-06T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
            </map>
        </property>
   </bean>
    <bean id="csvInsertSellerContact"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          singleton="false">
        <description>Inserts Seller Contact names from CSV file into Account object.</description>
        <property name="name" value="csvInsertSellerContact"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\csvInsertSellerContact.log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="username@username.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="EncryptedPassword"/>
                     <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\key.txt"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="540"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Contact"/>
                     <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Entity_Code__c"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="upsert"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\SellerContactMapping.sdl"/>
                <entry key="process.outputError" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\errorInsertSellerContact.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\Error Success Files\successInsertSellerContact.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="\\SFLoadFiles\SSIS Data Loader\CSV Files\SellerContacts_1_100.csv" />
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" /> 
                <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2007-06-06T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
            </map>
        </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```